# Ceedling Selectable YML File

Tags: ubuntu, ceedling

I am using Jenkins on Ubuntu 20.04 to automate my build process. Two projects have been given to me and they are heavily coupled. I will work on separating the two but first I need some tests set up. The two projects are PNE and BLDC for reference.

The two projects share some code filtered by ifdefs. In my ceedling tests I created two yml files. `bldc_project.yml` and `pne_project.yml`. Each YML file defines the necessary variables and point to the tests to be ran for each project.

To run my tests I do

```
set CEEDLING_MAIN_PROJECT_FILE=pne_project.yml
ceedling clobber test:all
```

This works on windows, I have tested this with `bldc_project.yml` and `pne_project.yml` the correct tests are run. When I perform this on my Jenkins server I get errors that `clobber` and `test:all` commands cannot be found.

It appears set is not creating the environment variable as expected. What am I doing wrong? Should I be using a different command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there is an issue in ceedling. I have solved the issue using symbolic links as so.

```
ln bldc_project.yml project.yml
ceedling clobber test:all
mv build/artifacts/test/report.xml bldc_report.xml
rm project.yml
```